# Efficient way to use regex compile (Python) with a list of 10.000 strings

Tags: python, regex, list, pyspark, pytorch

I got a list which contains approx. 10.000 strings and I want to use a regex pattern to detect this in this list. When I use re.compile it takes a lot of time to only apply one regex pattern. Is there any way with Python to make it faster?

Here my code:

```
import re

list_of_strings = ["I like to eat meat", "I don't like to eat meat", "I like to eat fish", "I don't like to eat fish"]

outcome = [x for x in list_of_strings if len(re.compile(r"I like to eat (.*?)").findall(x)) != 0]

Out[6]: ['I like to eat meat', 'I like to eat fish']
```

Here I have just 4 strings to demonstrate the case. In reality the code should handle 10.000 strings.

I could also use multiple processing to solve this issue but maybe there is also another solution with pytorch, pyspark or other Frameworks existing.

[Edit]
Thanks for all answers. I should have mentioned that every string is an article. So, it is not just one sentence to be handled from regex.

I also want to say that the regex here ist not that problem. So this is not a topic to be discussed.

Comment: `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern does not consume any text, you may just remove it and the regex output will stay the same.

Comment: If the patterns you  want to match are like your example (i.e. constant literal at the beginning of the string), the fastest way to do this is to **not** use regexps but `startswith` - `outcome = [x for x in list_of_strings if x.startswith('I like to eat')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also consider looping the list.

```
new_list = []
for item in list_of_strings:
    if 'I like to eat' in item:
        new_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.compile` is designed to be used only once.
Compile once then use the compiled regex that is more efficient.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"I like to eat (.*?)")
list_of_strings = ["I like to eat meat", "I don't like to eat meat", "I like to eat fish", "I don't like to eat fish"]

outcome = [x for x in list_of_strings if pattern.match(x)]
```

Your example is a good one to illustrate the use of `re.compile()`, i.e. when you use the regex intensively.